# Webview not functioning properly in android studio

Tags: android

Problem Area :
I am using webview and its loading the page and everything is functioning properly but i am getting one issue i.e in the website there is a whatsapp icon on clicking on which will lead you to the bussiness whatsapp account chatbox but that feature is not working properly in my webview but if i open same website on my mobile browser everything is working fine i.e when i click on whatsapp icon its navigating me to whatsapp bussiness  account chatbox and all, so can you please tell me where exactly in code i am doing wrong
Error i am getting when i am clicking on whatsapp icon in webview **No Internet Connection** but webview is working fine with other things like loading the web content and all and also in **manifest file i have already added internet permission and state network permission**
Website link : [Click here](https://www.bastibazar.com/products)
Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
ProgressBar progressBar;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("NEWS");
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.bastibazar.com/products");
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            try {
                webView.stopLoading();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }



            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
            super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });
     }

    public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
// This method is used to detect back button
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
   <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:max="3"
    android:progress="100"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forcefully executing the alert dialog for no internet connection in your webview.setWebViewClient

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
```

So remove this code..

Try below solution 
links with a custom URI scheme don't load automatically to launch apps from a android WebView.

add a custom WebViewClient to your WebView:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

then in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), have the following code:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView webView, final String url) {

if (url.startsWith("my.special.scheme://")) {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

    // The following flags launch the app outside the current app
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    activity.startActivity(intent);

    return true;
}  

return false;
```

}

Comment: it will then not show the dailog if user is not connected with internet and also what is my.special.scheme:// ?

Comment: also if possible can you the changes in my code because then it shall be more easier for me to understand what exactly u are trying to do,Thanks

Comment: also i tried  your code in my ide, activity is getting red is it a local variable?